# Flat rate Shipping classes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to achieve the following with the out of the box version of Woocommerce without any addons.

Three shipping options:

```
Gift card only - £3.00
Small Package - £5.00
Large Package -£10.00
```

Now the above needs to be set in the following format:

- Single card will be £1.50
- 1-2 products will be £5.00
- 3 or more products will be £10.00 postage.

Additional rates are currently:

```
Flat rate - £5.00

Gift Card Only | -3.50| order
Large Package |10  | order
```

I've tried configuring the above with the Shipping classes and using additional rates. However can't see where to enter logic for a threshold within the basket. Anyone came across a good way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't look like flat rate shipping allows to define minimum quantities per option. You should look for extensions allowing that or consider writing your own modifications. Also, if I understand your pricing options correct, when buying under 7 cards its worth buying them each separately. That seems counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this Woocommerce flat rate along with the filter '[woocommerce_package_rates](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_package_rates/)'.

The filter has two parameter, available_shipping_methods and package. The package contains all the information all items in the cart.

You can code on function.php in this way

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'alter_shipping_charge', 10, 2);

function alter_shipping_charge($available_shipping_methods, $package){
     $shipping_class_arr = array();
     foreach ($package['contents'] as $key => $item) {
         $shipping_class_arr[] = ['data']->get_shipping_class();
     }
     //do something here with $shipping_class_arr and $available_shipping_methods

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using woocommerce table rate shipping plugin

here is link https://woocommerce.com/products/table-rate-shipping/

you can setup here your shipping rate based on your qty, weight and based on classes as well.

hope this will help you out. 
you can download this plugin free here : https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping